# data-targeturl in html - where can i find the target url in the code?

Tags: html, selenium, url

When writing automation for the following website, I am trying to understand the links structure, in the code instead of a href links there are "data-targeturl.." elements

https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sites?helpset=trial&sap-client=001

For example:
[image: data-target link example]

Where can I see in the code the Target URL for each link?
Thank you

Comment: what exatly you want to do? Do you want to select all the links under human capital management

Comment: @Ab123 no, I want to know and understand where this button will link to, and other similar links in that page. when it is written  "data-targeturl.." how can I know only from reading the code what is the target URL of those kind of links

Comment: Your question is not clear... could you elaborate more??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes, this website contain links, when you read the code of the page you see "data-targeturl.." for each link and not "a href.." links. I want to know what is the URL for each link that i see in the code. Thank you

Comment: Ok then you can find this element then click on it and after navigation get current URL...:)

Comment: lol... yes but i am looking for a way to know to url before navigating to this page. because I am building something automatic that should use this url before navigating to it